# Como mostrar o progresso de uma ProgressBar na TaskBar do S.O.?

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

Estou a utilizar um `javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar` e um `javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator`, e gostaria de saber se é possível (e como fazer) que seja mostrado o progresso na TaskBar do Sistema Operacional, como na imagem de exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse print é de algum programa feito em java?

Comment: Acho que isso aqui pode ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192528/how-can-you-send-information-to-the-windows-task-bar-from-java-o-javafx Não tenho como testar no momento, por isso não responderei